# How to differentiate between an update and an insert using sequelize upsert method?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, upsert

I have a sequelize model where I am doing an upsert like this

```
ResetToken.upsert({
    accountId,
    token,
}, {
    conflictFields: ['account_id'],
    fields: ['token'],
});
```

I want to return an HTTP status 201 when a new row is added and a status 200 otherwise
How do I distinguish whether the upsert statement actually inserted a new row or just updated an existing row in sequelize?

**EDIT 1**
My underlying database is postgres 14

Comment: It depends on what Db you use

Comment: @Anatoly how would it apply for postgres

Comment: `UPSERT` is designed for cases where you don't care.  If you care, then just do the `SELECT`, `if present UPDATE`, `else INSERT` sequence.

Comment: From Sequelize documentation: `returns an array with two elements, the first being the new record and the second being true if it was just created or false if it already existed (except on Postgres and SQLite, which can't detect this and will always return null instead of a boolean).`

Answer (score 0):

Sequelize provides a return like this (adapted to your example):

```
const [insert, created] = ResetToken.upsert({
    accountId,
    token,
}, {
    conflictFields: ['account_id'],
    fields: ['token'],
});
```

Where:

- `insert` is your object, whatever it is new or not
- `created` a boolean